# Unable to call method using instance

Tags: c#, .net

Why does the first way of calling method not work in following context? I am trying to use in another method of another class:

```
var center = Setting.CacheInstance.GetCentres(new Request
{
}); // this does not work 

var center2= Setting.GetCentres(new Request
{
}); // this works
```

Class:

```
public sealed class Setting 
{
    private static Lazy<Setting> lazy =
        new Lazy<Setting>(() => new Setting());

    public static Setting CacheInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (!lazy.IsValueCreated)
                lazy = new Lazy<Setting>(() => new Setting());
            return lazy.Value;
        }
    }

    private Setting()
    {
    }

    public static  List<string> GetCentres(Request request)
    {  
        return GetCentres(request);
    }

    private static  List<string> GetCentres(Request request)
    {
          //implementation
    }

}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You say it doesn't work but don't say *why*. Please give error messages.

Comment: you cannot declare two methods with the same name and signature that only differ in access modifiers. Just name the private one `GetCentresInternal` or something.

Comment: Try `var center = Setting.CacheInstance.GetCentres(new Request() { });`

Comment: @DavidG: It does not compile in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetCentres` is static, so you can only call it from the class, not from an instance.

`Setting.CacheInstance.GetCentres` first gets the instance, and then tries to call the static on it. Remove the static on the method:

```
public List<string> GetCentres(Request request)
{
    return GetCentres(request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also check this article of jon skeet : http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx ..all different ways to implement single ton pattern which you are trying to implement

---

first way is not working because its static method

```
 var center = Setting.CacheInstance.GetCentres(new Request
```

`GetCentres` is static method you cannot call it via isntace

**solution** - remvoe `static` make method accessible via instance, there is no extra check in your property getter

```
public sealed class Setting 
    {
       private static Lazy<Setting> lazy =
       new Lazy<Setting>(() => new Setting());

        public static Setting CacheInstance
        {
            get
            {
                return lazy.Value;
            }
        }

        private Setting()
        {
        }

        public List<string> GetCentres(Request request)
        {

            return GetCentres(request);
        }

        //you cannot have two methos with same name and same parameter that 
        //is also issue 
        //private List<string> GetCentres(Request request)
        //{
          //implementation
        //}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetCentres` is a static method, therefore you won't be able to invoke it using an instance of the class. You need to either invoke it by using the class itself (so `Setting.GetCentres`), or remove the `static` qualifier from the method. You have more information in [the official C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).

Answer (score 0):

In C#, static members cannot be accessed with instance.Static members belong to the class instead of a specific instance.It means that only one instance of a static field exists or you don't create any. It will be shared by all instances.

```
Setting.GetCentres()
```

Or

Remove the static modifier from GetCentres ()

```
public  List<string> GetCentres(Request request)
        {

            return GetCentres(request);
        }
```